# CakePhp 2.5 $belongsTo in two models

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

Right now I have this:
Groups
Inside Groups we have Subgroups
Inside Subgroups we have Comments

Subgroups belongs to Groups 1, 2, 3 ; subgroups table have `group_id` field
Comments belongs to Subgroups A, B, C ; comments table have `subgroup_id` field

My models:

CommentsGroup.php

```
<?php

App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class CommentsGroup extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'comment_groups';

}
```

CommentsSubGroup.php

```
<?php

App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class CommentsSubGroup extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'comment_subgroups';

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'CommentsGroup' => array(
            'className'  => 'CommentsGroup',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => ['`CommentsGroup`.`id` = `CommentsSubGroup`.`group_id`']
        )
    );

}
```

Comment.php

```
<?php

App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Comment extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'CommentsSubGroup' => array(
            'className' => 'CommentsSubGroup',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => ['`CommentsSubGroup`.`id` = `Comment`.`subgroup_id`']
        )
    );

}
```

When I try from my controller to get the subgroup_id related to the comment it's ok. When I try to get more (the group_id linked to the subgroup_id), I fail.

Query without recursive is ok, otherwise I have:

```
$data = $this->_Model->find('all', ['conditions' => ['subgroup_id' => $id], 'recursive' => 2, 'order' => [$this->_Modelname . '.id' => 'DESC']]);
```

Take in consideration `$this->_Model` equals to `Comment` .

The error I have:

> Database Error Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown
>   column 'CommentsSubGroup.group_id' in 'where clause'
>
> SQL Query: SELECT `CommentsGroup`.`id`, `CommentsGroup`.`name` FROM
>   `botobot_comments`.`comment_groups` AS `CommentsGroup` WHERE
>   `CommentsGroup`.`id` = `CommentsSubGroup`.`group_id`

Any guess ? Or I am wrong and I should use $hasMany relationship ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in using a belongsTo relationship but you need to specify the `foreignKey` attribute in order for the relationships to work. You also need to take the join condition out of the `conditions` key (as Cake can figure that out based on the foreign key).

For example:

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Comment extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'CommentsSubGroup' => array(
            'className' => 'CommentsSubGroup',
            'foreignKey' => 'subgroup_id'
        )
    );

}
```

You also need to follow Cakes naming convention with your models and tables otherwise youll need to explicitly declare your table names and primary keys in their respective models.

In your case, `CommentsSubGroup` should be `CommentSubGroup` which would assume the table called comment_sub_group and a primary key of comment_sub_group_id

Comment: I am still having the same error. And if we check the error, the query is missing one alias, and a left join. Something else is missing somewhere ... :S

Comment: It’s likely due to your models not following the proper naming convention - see my updated reply.

Comment: Yes as I am working on an already existing db, I can't follow the good naming conventions. Btw even with the updated code,  still getting the same error.